# ConvertViewportPointToGeoCoordinate gives null in WP8.0

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to get the coordinates for top left and bottom right corners of the Map control.  I'm using ConvertViewportPointToGeoCoordinate to do this but for some reason, it's doesn't result in a value when using WP 8.0 but it works when using WP 8.1.  Any ideas on why this is happening?

XAML:

```
<Controls:Map x:Name="RMap2" Width="400" Height="400" ZoomLevel="7" Loaded="RMap2_Loaded" TransformCenter="0,0" />
```

C#:

```
GeoCoordinate topLeft = RMap2.ConvertViewportPointToGeoCoordinate(new Point(0, 0));
GeoCoordinate bottomRight = RMap2.ConvertViewportPointToGeoCoordinate(new Point(400, 400));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the pitch equal to the zoom level before conversion.

```
GeoCoordinate topLeft = new GeoCoordinate();
GeoCoordinate bottomRight = new GeoCoordinate();
try
{
    //Set pitch to zoom level so ConvertViewpointToGeoCoordinate does not return null in 8.0
    RMap2.Pitch = RMap2.ZoomLevel;
    topLeft = RMap2.ConvertViewportPointToGeoCoordinate(new Point(0, 0));
    bottomRight = RMap2.ConvertViewportPointToGeoCoordinate(new Point(400, 400));
}
catch {  }
//Resets pitch to 0.0 so the map looks 2D
//These lines of code execute so quickly the user will not see the pitch change
RMap2.Pitch = 0.0;
```

It's worth noting that if your map is not visible, you will get null during the conversions. You may want to consider using a radius instead, if possible. Here's an example:

```
//Declare radius variable
double radius;
try
{
    //Set pitch to zoom level so ConvertViewpointToGeoCoordinate does not return null in 8.0
    RMap2.Pitch = RMap2.ZoomLevel;
    //Gets the distance between the center and the center left edge in meters
    radius = RMap2.Center.GetDistanceTo(radarMap.ConvertViewportPointToGeoCoordinate(new Point(0, 200)));
    //Converts meters to nautical miles
    radius = radius * 0.00053996;
}
//If your map is not visible, ConvertViewpointToGeoCoordinate will return null, and you better have a good backup plan
//Since this usually only happens when the app is first loading, I have determined the distance for when zoom level is 7.0 (using the code above, I just set the zoom level to 7.0, and then set a breakpoint on the last line to check the radius)
//You could do other things here like change it to visible
catch { RMap2.ZoomLevel = 7.0; radius = 98.766450549077661; }
//Resets pitch to 0.0 so the map looks 2D
//These lines of code execute so quickly the user will not see the pitch change
RMap2.Pitch = 0.0;
```

Hope this helps.